# Frequently saving text editor

Tags: text-editors

Is there a FREE text editor for WINDOWS that can be set to save the current file after any changes or every second or faster?

Comment: just curious, why do you want it to save every SECOND?

Answer (score 7):

You can use Notepad++ with some customized scripts.

For example, [this forum post gives a sample script](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic28171.html).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> to save. That should speed up saving considerably. Saving every second is overkill though, and may slow down your performance.

If you are not working on code, [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) has a pretty frequent autosave.

Answer (score 0):

[nvPY](https://github.com/cpbotha/nvpy) and [ResophNotes](http://www.resoph.com/ResophNotes/Welcome.html) both automatically and continuously save and sync any changes to disk and online to simplenote.

Answer (score -1):

you could probably get a script for Vim, Emacs, or another programming editor